# $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ on $(0,1)$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have to prove

$$
f: (0,1) \to [-1,1], \ \ f(x)=x\sin(1/x)
$$

using $\epsilon-\delta$.

---

**Try**

Fix $\epsilon >0$. I have

$$
\left|x \sin(1/x) - y \sin (1/y)\right| \le |\sin (1/x)| |x-y| + |y| |\sin (1/x) - \sin(1/y)|
$$

I can control $|\sin (1/x)| |x-y|$ part, since I can control $|x-y|$ and $|\sin(1/x)| \le 1$. But I don't know how to deal with $|y| |\sin (1/x) - \sin(1/y)|$ part.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(a)-\sin(b)=2\sin\left(\dfrac{a-b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Are you sure that this function is uniformly continuous?

Comment: @AndréPorto Since $g(x) = x \sin (1/x) \mathbb{1}_{x \neq 0}$, $g:[0,1] \to [-1,1]$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous, thus $f$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: Graphically, it is clearly uniformly continuous.

Comment: I got so frustrated with this that I Googled around and found this: http://mathhelpforum.com/differential-geometry/161946-f-x-x-sin-1-x-uniformly-continuous.html

Comment: No idea if that tricky middle step is correct, but from the result it is easy to see what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the prosthaphaereis formula

$$|y| \left|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y} \right| = 2|y|\left|\sin \frac{x^{-1}-y^{-1}}{2} \right| \left|\cos \frac{x^{-1}+y^{-1}}{2} \right| \leqslant 2|y|\left|\frac{x^{-1} - y^{-1}}{2} \right| \\\leqslant \frac{|x-y|}{|x|}$$

WLOG assume $x > y$ -- otherwise, work with the alternative estimate $|x| \left|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y} \right|$.

Note that we also have

$$|y| \left|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y} \right| \leqslant 2|y|$$

Suppose $|x - y| < \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$.  Either $|y| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and we have

$$|y| \left|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y} \right| \leqslant 2\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon,$$

or

$$|x| > |y| \geqslant \frac{\epsilon}{2},$$

and

$$|y| \left|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y} \right|\leqslant \frac{|x-y|}{|x|} < \frac{2}{\epsilon} \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} = \epsilon$$

Thus, $|x-y| < \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$ implies $|y| \left|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y} \right|\leqslant \epsilon$ for all $x,y \in (0,1)$.

The estimate on the first line is only sharp enough to prove uniform continuity on an interval $[a,1)$ where $a > 0$.  However, we know that $x \sin \frac{1}{x} \to 0 $ as $x \to 0$ and this implies continuous extendibility to $[0,1)$ and, hence uniform continuity on $(0,1)$.  The argument above combines both of these elements into an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof.

Comment: This also is a variation on the proof that for $f \in C([0,\infty)) $, if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and  is finite, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thx for the beautiful proof, although I have not understood the final paragraph...

Comment: @Moreblue: You're welcome.  The last paragraph is just some extra color. It's not essential. What I'm saying is the bound $|x-y|/|x|$ obtained at the beginning of the proof is fine for proving uniform continuity on a compact interval where $x> a>0$ since $1/|x|<1/a$ but we have a problem if $x$ can get close to $0$.   The trick I used to take care of that works because the $x \sin(1/x)$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Wow, this really was rather involved for a usual e-d proof. Nicely done.